# Add Worksheet in external workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add worksheet call "Master Record" in existing excel file. With the below code, I am able to create the worksheet but if the worksheet is already exit, it is creating sheet with different name Eg: Sheet2, Sheet3.

I don't want to create any other sheets. It it is already exist than just reflect message. Please advise as to how can I avoid creating unnecessary sheet.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text)
Set ws = Wb.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "Master Records"

Wb.Save
Wb.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it exists.

```
Dim exists as Boolean
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text)    


exists = False

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
   If Worksheets(i).Name = "Master Records" Then
      exists = True
   End If
   If exists = True Then 'Exit loop early if it finds that the sheet exists
      Exit For
   End If
Next i

If Not exists Then
Set ws = Wb.Sheets.Add
   ws.Name = "Master Records"
Else
   MsgBox("Sheet Exists")
End If
```

Comment: Still It is adding sheet2. I have the sheets called Master Records and Sheet1. When I run the code, it show a message as sheet already exist but create another sheet

Comment: Sorry. I didn't have time to test this earlier, have updated it now - Set ws=wb.sheets.Add needed to be moved.